# Error while retrieving objects from firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from 'src/app/service/category.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-product-form',
    templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
    categories$;

    constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
        this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
        console.log(this.categories$);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void { }
}



@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryService {
    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

    getCategories() {
        return this.db.list('/categories')
    }

}
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select id="category" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of (categories$|async)" [value]=""> {{c.name}} </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Trying to retrieve objects from firebase real-time database as shown in the image and getting the error shown in image 2.  How to fix it? Please help.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to use valueChange() :

```
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
    categories$;

    constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
        this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories().valueChanges();
        // console.log(this.categories$);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select id="category" class="form-control">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option *ngFor="let c of categories$|async" [value]=""> {{c.name}} </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what will i have to write in [value] = " "
Since c.$key is not working

Comment: it depends on the object, here is an example: [value] = "{{c.categoryID}}"

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(categoryService:CategoryService, private productService:ProductService) { 

    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories().snapshotChanges();

  }



 <option class="form-control" *ngFor="let c of (categories$|async)" [value]="c.key"> {{c.payload.val().name}} </option>



getCategories() {

    return this.db.list('/categories', ref => (ref.orderByChild('name')));

  }
```

This is giving me the right result.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.db.list('/categories').snapshotChanges();` in your service.

```
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getCategories(){
    return this.db.list('/categories').snapshotChanges();
  }
}
```

```
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$: Observable<SnapshotAction<unknown>[]>;

  constructor(categoryService: CategoryService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Also in ProductFormComponent.html

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async" [value]="c.key">
            {{ c.payload.val()["name"] }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```